# How deterministic is a Linux system startup sequence?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I just did a small experiment: I  configured a vanilla Ubuntu Linux installed some days before with `atime` mount option for the root fs. I then restarted a few times, running some out-of-the-box applications and finally shut it down gracefully.
I then booted the machine from some live image, and removed any file from Ubuntu not accessed by the last days. 
I then tried to reboot Ubuntu. It fails to black screen at early boot.

I repeated the experiment several times, carefully checking for fs settings and introduced an increasing past time window for the files kept. I never managed to get Ubuntu boot into Unity.

Which crucial files may be missing, that are needed for boot, but where never accessed before?

Comment: *"It fails to black screen at early boot."* -- That's a useless description for diagnosing what went wrong.  *"removed any file from Ubuntu not accessed by the last days."* -- Bad grammar aside, the bootloader can/will access the filesystem without updating the access times.

Comment: You are the one who deleted random files, how should we know what exactly you removed? You are obviously removing some critical system files. How about as part of your "experiment" you actually record exactly what you are deleting or before you delete random things you actually figure out what those things might be.

Comment: I am not deleting random things, but with a clear rationale of "files not accessed during boot". The only problem is, `atime` seems no reliable indicator for this if the filesystem is accessed read-only for some time. For `initrd`, I expect this and excluded the early boot files from deletion.

Comment: I also apologize for the difference between question title and contents, but there was no way to break the question about my procedure down to one line.

Answer (score 2):

> Which crucial files may be missing, that are needed for boot, but were never accessed before?

I think it's not about "never accessed before", but rather "their new access times couldn't be stored", because in general some stages of booting process read filesystem(s) in read-only fashion.

It's not that something bypasses the `atime` feature on purpose. Access time not being updated is just a side effect of preliminary read-only mounting (to store the new atime you need to write it, right?). I expect it applies especially to `initrd` and `vmlinuz` in `/boot`, but the root filesystem is initially mounted read-only as well:

> Thus, the kernel initializes devices, mounts the root filesystem specified by the boot loader as read only, and runs Init (`/sbin/init`) ...

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process#Kernel_startup_stage))

Then whatever acts as Init (it's `systemd` in Ubuntu) remounts the filesystem as read-write at some point. [For `systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-remount-fs.service.html):

> `systemd-remount-fs.service` is an early boot service that applies mount options listed in `fstab(5)` to the root file system [...]

So when I read this statement of yours: "It fails to black screen at early boot", I'm guessing you removed some file(s) that need to be accessed only during these early read-only boot stages when atime cannot be updated.

---

Another pitfall (that in the end seems irrelevant to your case, but it's good to know):

From [`man 8 mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man8/mount.8.html) [emphasis mine]:

> `atime`
>
> **Do  not  use  the  `noatime`  feature**, so the inode access time is controlled by kernel **defaults**.  See also the descriptions of the `relatime` and `strictatime` mount options.
>
> **`relatime`**
>
> Update  inode  access  times  relative to modify or change time. Access time is only updated if  the  previous  access  time  was earlier  than  the  current  modify or change time. (Similar to `noatime`, but it doesn't break `mutt` or  other applications that need  to know if a file has been read since the last time it was modified.)
>
> Since Linux 2.6.30, **the kernel defaults to the behavior provided by this   option (unless `noatime` was specified)**, and the `strictatime` option is required to obtain traditional semantics. In  addition, since Linux 2.6.30, the file's last access time is always updated if it is more than 1 day old.

This "1 day old" condition along with OS "installed some days before", and with removing files "not accessed by the last days" -- this all makes default `relatime` irrelevant to your issue, I think. Still you may have thought `atime` option is enough to make access time be updated every time; so I thought it would be good to explain this.

Comment: In case of `/boot` resp. `initrd` I was aware of it and excluded it from deletion. However, if there is read-only access out of  `initrd` into `/` then this could be the issue. But as the needed fs setup is done in `initrd`, there should be no reason for doing so? I thought mounting `/` and pivot root where the last steps carried out by `initrd` provided code..